# file_get_contents giving garbage for Russian content

Tags: php, character-encoding, file-get-contents

I am trying my best to describe my problem. For a client PC, I am reading a file (Via ::ReadFile) and uploading i tto a PHP server (HTTP upload). I am receiving this string in that PHP via following file code and saving in hard disk:

```
<?php
// body contains sent data here
    $body = file_get_contents('php://input',FILE_TEXT);
    echo "<script language= 'JavaScript'>alert(' . $body . ');</script>";
        $today = date("dmY-Gis");
        $name = $today . ".log";
        //$body = utf8_encode($body);
        //$body = "\xEF\xBB\xBF".$body;
        $f = fopen($name, "wb");
        fwrite($f, $body);
        fclose($f);
php?>
```

Now, I have a string sending as follows: выфпвыфп  Notepad

But this PHP script is saving it as ???????? Notepad

Seems english strings are captured correctly, but non - English string is not collected

Can any one have idea.

- [file_get_contents not working with utf8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917714/file-get-contents-not-working-with-utf8?rq=1)
- [php: file_get_contents encoding problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713293/php-file-get-contents-encoding-problem)

Above two are same problem but none gave any solutions that worked for me.

Comment: Do you have a character encoding set in your document?

Comment: What encoding is the data sent in and what encoding are you trying to interpret it in?

Comment: As @WaleedKhan mentioned, try with <meta charset='utf-8' /> or something similar on your document

Comment: The document which I am reading have Unicode, it fine, it is sending currect strings (I saw it from debuggung). But the out puts tring is in ANSII format. I tried to make it utf-8 using //$body = utf8_encode($body);
        //$body = "\xEF\xBB\xBF".$body;  But it won't occured

Comment: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: Thanks deceze, it is  awesome link

Answer (score 0):

**add this**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
```

**to your page**